# Convert list of strings into list of integers

Tags: python, list

I need to convert a string of 2 items (separated by a comma) to integers.

from:

```
[['(0,3)', '(1,2)', '(2,2)'], ['(0,3)', '(1,2)', '(2,2)']]
```

to:

```
[[(0,3), (1,2), (2,2)], [(0,3), (1,2), (2,2)]]
```

Comment: It looks simple enough that you could use regular expressions to split the internal strings: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html ; you could use such expressions inside a couple of list comprehensions to handle the entire list. You could also split the string manually, but it would be less readable than re's.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) for the task:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

lst = [["(0,3)", "(1,2)", "(2,2)"], ["(0,3)", "(1,2)", "(2,2)"]]

lst = [[literal_eval(v) for v in l] for l in lst]
print(lst)
```

Prints:

```
[[(0, 3), (1, 2), (2, 2)], [(0, 3), (1, 2), (2, 2)]]
```

---

EDIT: Another approach (thanks @S3DEV):

```py
out = [list(map(literal_eval, sub_list)) for sub_list in lst]
```

Quick benchmark:

```py
from timeit import timeit
from ast import literal_eval

lst = [["(0,3)", "(1,2)", "(2,2)"], ["(0,3)", "(1,2)", "(2,2)"]]


def fn1():
    return [[literal_eval(v) for v in l] for l in lst]


def fn2():
    return [list(map(literal_eval, sub_list)) for sub_list in lst]


assert fn1() == fn2()

t1 = timeit(lambda: fn1(), number=1_000)
t2 = timeit(lambda: fn2(), number=1_000)

print(t1)
print(t2)
```

Prints on my machine (AMD 3700X, Python 3.9.7):

```
0.040873110003303736                                                                                                                                                                                           
0.04002662200946361
```

Comment: Was just testing this myself.  `list(map(literal_eval, sub_list))` can be used on each sub-list, which *might* perform quicker(?) than double iteration. (GMTA upvote). :-)

Comment: @S3DEV I've added your solution to my answer + quick benchmark (it's roughly the same).

Comment: @AndrejKesely for large data second one can beat the first one.

Comment: @SharimIqbal I've tried it for `lst = [["(0,3)", "(1,2)", "(2,2)"] * 100, ["(0,3)", "(1,2)", "(2,2)"] * 100]`. The result is still the ~same (3.86 vs 3.85)

Comment: Try `literal_eval = str`, what times do you get then?

Comment: @KellyBundy For `[["(0,3)", "(1,2)", "(2,2)"] * 1000,["(0,3)", "(1,2)", "(2,2)"] * 1000] * 100` and with `literal_eval = str`, `number=1` I've got `0.05840949004050344/0.042647327994927764`. So yeah, the `map()` has speedup. With `literal_eval` the results are roughly the same (3.98 vs 3.93)

Comment: Ha, actually that was not my point. Point was to show that `literal_eval` takes like 97% of the time, so that optimizing the remaining 3% can't help much.

Comment: With that larger data you tested, it's even more like 99% vs 1%.

Answer (score 1):

If you input always in the pattern.

```py
lst = [['(0,3)', '(1,2)', '(2,2)'], ['(0,3)', '(1,2)', '(2,2)']]

new_lst = list(map(lambda i:[eval(a,{}) for a in i],lst))
# OR

# new_lst = list(map(lambda i:list(map(lambda a:eval(a,{}),i)),lst))
print(new_lst)
```

OUTPUT

```
[[(0, 3), (1, 2), (2, 2)], [(0, 3), (1, 2), (2, 2)]]
```

```py
lst = [['(0,3)', '(1,2)', '(2,2)'], ['(0,3)', '(1,2)', '(2,2)']]
new_lst = []
for a in lst:
    l = []
    for i in a:
        i = i[1:-1].split(',')
        t = []
        for num in i:
            t.append(int(num))
        l.append(tuple(t))

    new_lst.append(l)

print(new_lst)
```

output

```
[[(0, 3), (1, 2), (2, 2)], [(0, 3), (1, 2), (2, 2)]]
```

OR Using Map Function

```
lst = [['(0,3)', '(1,2)', '(2,2)'], ['(0,3)', '(1,2)', '(2,2)']]

new_lst = [list(map(lambda e:tuple(map(lambda a:int(a),e[1:-1].split(','))),i)) for i in lst]
print(new_lst)
```

```
[[(0, 3), (1, 2), (2, 2)], [(0, 3), (1, 2), (2, 2)]]
```